# I have to add label and text field in one row programmatically with autolayout constraint but project crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-autolayout

here is my code. 
I have to add label and text field in one row programmatically by adding  autolayout constraint  but project crash due to constraint not set properly
plz help me to solve this error

```
-(void)autoLayoutProgrametacally
{

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
UIImage *image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"];
[imgView setImage:image];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];

NSArray *imageViewHorConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[imgView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imgView)];
NSArray *imageViewVerConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[imgView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imgView)];

[self.view addConstraints:imageViewHorConst];
[self.view addConstraints:imageViewVerConst];


UILabel *FirstName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[FirstName setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[FirstName setNumberOfLines:1];
[FirstName setText:@"First Name:"];
[self.view addSubview:FirstName];
UILabel *LastName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[LastName setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[LastName setNumberOfLines:1];
[LastName setText:@"Last Name:"];
[self.view addSubview:LastName];
UITextField *txtFirstName=[[UITextField alloc]init];
[txtFirstName setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
UITextField *txtLastName=[[UITextField alloc]init];
[txtLastName setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];




NSArray *FirstNameVerConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(10)-[FirstName]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(FirstName)];
NSArray *FirstNameHorConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(10)-[FirstName(txtFirstName)]-(10)-[txtFirstName]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:nil views:@{@"FirstName":FirstName, @"txtFirstName":txtFirstName}];
NSArray *LastNameVerConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[LastName]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(LastName)];
NSArray *LastNameHorConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[LastName(txtLastName)]-(10)-[txtLastName]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:nil views:@{@"LastName":LastName, @"txtLastName":txtLastName}];


[self.view addConstraints:FirstNameVerConst];
[self.view addConstraints:FirstNameHorConst];
[self.view addConstraints:LastNameVerConst];
[self.view addConstraints:LastNameHorConst];
}
```

Comment: where is the frame of your Imageview or textfield?

Comment: you are adding constraints to rootview add those constraints to your textfield,label and imageview

Comment: what is the error report you are getting?

Comment: Am getting this error while am trying to run '[UIView _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited the code...try this maybe this will help...
replace your code with this one...

```
-(void)autoLayoutProgrametacally
{

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
UIImage *image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"];
[imgView setImage:image];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];

NSArray *imageViewHorConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[imgView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imgView)];
NSArray *imageViewVerConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[imgView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imgView)];

[self.view addConstraints:imageViewHorConst];
[self.view addConstraints:imageViewVerConst];


UILabel *FirstName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[FirstName setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[FirstName setNumberOfLines:1];
[FirstName setText:@"First Name:"];
FirstName.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:FirstName];

UITextField *txtFirstName=[[UITextField alloc]init];
txtFirstName.placeholder=@"FirstName";
txtFirstName.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
txtFirstName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
txtFirstName.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
txtFirstName.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];
txtFirstName.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
[self.view addSubview:txtFirstName];

UILabel *LastName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[LastName setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[LastName setNumberOfLines:1];
[LastName setText:@"Last Name:"];
LastName.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:LastName];

UITextField *txtLastName=[[UITextField alloc]init];
txtLastName.placeholder=@"LastName";
txtLastName.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
txtLastName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
txtLastName.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
txtLastName.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];
txtLastName.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
[self.view addSubview:txtLastName];




NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"height":@30.0};

NSArray *FirstNameVerConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(30)-[FirstName(25)]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(FirstName)];
NSArray *FirstNameHorConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[FirstName(txtFirstName)]-10-[txtFirstName(250)]-10-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:metrics views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(FirstName,txtFirstName)];



NSArray *LastNameVerConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[FirstName(LastName)]-[LastName(25)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"FirstName":FirstName , @"LastName":LastName }];


NSArray *LastNameHorConst = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[LastName(txtLastName)]-10-[txtLastName(250)]-10-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:metrics views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(LastName,txtLastName)];

[self.view addConstraints:FirstNameVerConst];
[self.view addConstraints:FirstNameHorConst];
[self.view addConstraints:LastNameVerConst];
[self.view addConstraints:LastNameHorConst];
}
```